# HBase PerformanceEvaluation, how can I assign columnFamily and column name?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I use `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation`, Hbase already have a table named test, so I run hbase:

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation --nomapred --table=test randomWrite 1.

but it can't work. And in usage, I have no found how can I assign `columnFamily` and column name.

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2804 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family info does not exist in region testpe,,1427097792288.f5a12ab39df73ed455984cdb7598eed8. in table 'testpe', {NAME => 'f1', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.doBatchOp(HRegionServer.java:4408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(HRegionServer.java:3584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:30000)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2078)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
: 2804 times, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation.doLocalClients(PerformanceEvaluation.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation.runTest(PerformanceEvaluation.java:1158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation.run(PerformanceEvaluation.java:1391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation.main(PerformanceEvaluation.java:1412)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2804 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family info does not exist in region testpe,,1427097792288.f5a12ab39df73ed455984cdb7598eed8. in table 'testpe', {NAME => 'f1', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.doBatchOp(HRegionServer.java:4408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(HRegionServer.java:3584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:30000)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2078)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
: 2804 times, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1700(AsyncProcess.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:1069)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$RandomWriteTest.testRow(PerformanceEvaluation.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$Test.testTimed(PerformanceEvaluation.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$Test.test(PerformanceEvaluation.java:671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation.runOneClient(PerformanceEvaluation.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$1.call(PerformanceEvaluation.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$1.call(PerformanceEvaluation.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation --nomapred --table='test' randomWrite 1